# Problem with special character WordPress

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I have a WordPress and everything seems perfectly fine but I have this page that has title 77% and it shows error 404 page. 
How can I fix this? I am kind of sure it is because of the % in the 77%. The permalink uses the 77 but for some reason wordpress still doesn't like that % in the title. What can I do to fix this while keeping the % there?

Comment: your problem is not the '%', could you show us the code you are using?

Comment: what do you mean the code i am using? i said i am using wordpress so i don't get what code you want

Comment: My bad, normally we discuss coding issues in here, so that was my first guess, not from the back-end point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do, the % symbol is not a neutral character and whatever 2 characters  immediatly follow it are used to represent a character. This is called percent encoding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

For example, to encode a % you would use %25.

Thus the answer is:

**No, it is not possible to fix this while keeping the % there, because URLs are percent encoded.**

Should by some stroke of luck you manage to get it working, I would recommend still avoiding it due to the misuse of the % symbol

Comment: so take the % symbol off? You are really sure no way around this at all?

Comment: also remember i told you that the permalink itself is using 77 just the title uses 77%...so with that permalink..why won't it still work? And is it because of that % that i get the error 404 page?

Comment: basically, take the '%' of the link, you can keep it in the title itself but remove it from the link structure...

Comment: so is there or is there not a % character in the URL?

Comment: can you provide me with an example URL?

Comment: Of reference: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/569

Comment: fixed..i just added % to the permalink so made the permalink also 77% and it added 77%25 itself...working now but permalink has 77%25 automatically..at least working now with 77% as title..thanks

Comment: I've made numerous posts on my local wordpress installs with '%' characters in the title and have had no issues loading them

Comment: Aha glad it's working now

Answer (score -1):

I got this problem too.

First, when I saw it happening, I had to edit the permalink removing the % there. OK.

Second step, I had to search in permalink field in DB, replacing/removing all %. So, just removing it with a replace SQL command.

Third step? Remember to write the title of a new post, save a draft, see the permalink and edit it to remove the % and start write the content of the post.

I tried to see the hard code, and the command responsible to remove special characters and this function is there and the % is also there. So, I can't explain what it happens, but it's not removing it as well.

Comment: The question was not how to remove the % from the post, but rather how to have the % be allowed as part of the title. See the last line of their question: "...while keeping the % there.". Also directly search and replacing for "%" in the database is dangerous if not done right, and I'm not sure I'd recommend it without great need and many warnings.